# Suma Sql Server con condicion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select distinct GETDATE() as Fecha_Actual, f353_fecha_vcto, DATEDIFF(day, 
f353_fecha_vcto, GETDATE()) AS Dias_Vencidos, 
f353_consec_docto_cruce, f353_total_db, f353_total_cr, f353_total_db - 
f353_total_cr AS Valores
from t350_co_docto_contable
INNER JOIN t200_mm_terceros ON 
t200_mm_terceros.f200_rowid=t350_co_docto_contable.f350_rowid_tercero
INNER JOIN t353_co_saldo_abierto ON 
t353_co_saldo_abierto.f353_rowid_docto=t350_co_docto_contable.f350_rowid
INNER JOIN t354_co_mov_saldo_abierto ON 
t354_co_mov_saldo_abierto.f354_rowid_docto
=t350_co_docto_contable.f350_rowid
INNER JOIN t351_co_mov_docto ON 
t351_co_mov_docto.f351_rowid_docto=t350_co_docto_contable.f350_rowid
WHERE f350_id_tipo_docto LIKE 'FV%' AND f200_nit = '1035877400' AND 
f350_id_periodo >= '201807' AND f351_id_periodo >= '201807'
AND f353_total_db - f353_total_cr <> 0 ORDER BY Dias_Vencidos
```

Estos son los resultados de la consulta:

[image: Resultados]

Lo que necesito hacer es lo siguiente:
crear en la consulta una columna `Vencidos` y me sume las cifras del campo `Valores` con la condición de que el campo `Dias_Vencidos` sea mayor a 0

Si el valor de los `Dias_Vencidos` es menor o igual a 0 me va a hacer lo mismo pero no en la columna `Vencidos` si no en una columna `Corriente`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que necesitas para tu problema es aplicar un **[CASE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT t.campo1, 
CASE WHEN t.Dias_Vencidos > 0 THEN SUM(t.Valores) ELSE 0 END 'Vencidos',
CASE WHEN t.Dias_Vencidos < 0 THEN SUM(t.Valores) ELSE 0 END 'Corriente'
FROM tuTabla t
GROUP BY t.campo1, t.Dias_Vencidos
```

Nos comentas

Comment: Disculpa, me podrías decir como implemento eso a mi script actual? la verdad yo no uso el SQL para hacer condicionales ni nada por el estilo y me pierdo un poco

Comment: Si no me equivoco, las dos lineas del "case" puedes colocarlas antes del "from" de tu sentencia SQL, la última linea del "group by" tiene que ir al final de toda tu consulta, probablemente antes del "order by".

Comment: @JuanManuelPalacios está en lo correcto colega .. Nos comentas como te va!

Comment: Gracias a los dos, me funciono de maravilla.